# Programming with eclipse, not recognizing my android code in XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, color-scheme

I'm brand new to eclipse and programming and I'm following video tutorials but I can't figure out why my eclipse doesn't recognizing the coding. In the video I see that he adds

```
android:gravity=center
android:background="@color/red"
```

and it changes color but mine does not..
the `android:gravity` changes to a pink color and the =... changes to blue but mine stays black and when I look at the graphic layout the code is not registering

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
    android:gravity=center
    android:background="@color/red"
<TextView  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/red" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the corrected Code,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="#ff0000"
    >
    <TextView  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="@string/red" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Color can be also defined in XML files.
Create a new xml file name color.xml inside /res/values.
Paste the following code inside

```
<color name="red">#FF0000</color>
```

Also Make sure you have the following line in strings.xml

```
 <string name="red">Your text</string>
```

and change the code as follows.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@color/red"
    >
    <TextView  
         android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
         android:text="@string/red" 
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot i realized it was something as simple as ">"

Comment: u r welcome... user696087.. U have any name or screen name??? it seems little difficult to call u that way...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">
     -----------------
    android:gravity=center
    android:background="@color/red"
    -----------------
```

That bit is wrong. It has be declared inside the layout object. Remove it.

```
<TextView  
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:text="@string/red" android:layout_width="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Have you declared the color red in your resource folder under string xml file?

[Read](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html)

Answer (score 0):

- Missing the quotes in `android:gravity="center"`
- You need to create a color resource: `<color name="red">#FF0000</color>`

You can find the documentation for the color resource here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html